# Possible to be anonymous from contacts on TG groups?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook, node-telegram-bot-api

TG claims to be very private - my question is - is it possible to be part of a TG group that you *have* fellow contacts on, but those fellow contacts *not* to know you are on that group? So is it possible that 2 acquaintances message each other without knowing they are actually messaging acquaintances that are on each other’s contact list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to be part of a TG group that you have fellow contacts on, but those fellow contacts not to know you are on that group? 
>   I will answer your question in 2 situation :

1. The person whom is in your contact list (with or without knowing his/her number).
2. The person whom is in **not** your contact list.

   - **First** I should say : Yes , you can add a person as your contact without knowing his/her number in [this](https://telegram.org/blog#june-2019) update of Telegram
   - **Second** : If you try to join a group, Telegram shows you a small list of group's members and in the first line of that popup you will see your contacts there like this image :

[image]

As you can see, the user with "Game" name is mine and my friend see my account in the first of list. This situation is also applies to a person whom you added without knowing his/her number.

- **Third**: You also can click on his/her account and see how much group do you have in common with him/her it will show list of all groups you have.

[image]

This situation is also applies to a person whom is not in your contact list.

Comment: So by your message, is it fair to say that if you have a person in your contact list (with or without his phone number), he and you will both know if you are on the same group and if he messages on the group, you will know which contact has messaged.

Comment: Exactly . So you can't be anonymous in groups/supergroups